# Lombok initialization inside NoArgsConstructor

Tags: java, lombok

Is it possible to roll a constructor with no arguments like below into lombok annotation?

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public abstract class Music implements IMusic {

    @NonNull
    protected Map<String, Song> songsCollection;

    // This one
    public Music(){
        songsCollection = new HashMap<>();
    }

    ...
}
```

I tried it with `@NoArgsConstructor` but it's just an empty block. I also combined `@Builder`, `@Singular`, `@Default` with no success.

Comment: Why not simply `protected HashMap<String, Song> songsCollection = new HashMap<>();` ?

Comment: @racraman And generally the first type should be `Map`, not `HashMap` (not your mistake, but you did preserve it)

Comment: @racraman In that case `@RequiredArgsConstructor` will not generate argument for `songsCollection`

Comment: @racraman Then use "AllArgsConstructor"

Comment: @Michael Indeed it should. Thanks!